# Android Emulator -Error comes when running android app

Tags: android

I got an error (below) when I run any android app.

```
[2011-03-10 09:07:24 - Emulator] NAND: could not create temp file for system NAND disk image: Invalid argument
```

Please tell me what should I do..

Thanks..

Comment: You might try creating a new Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to create a new Android emulator and launch it from the AVD Manager, selecting it and clicking Start.

Answer (score 1):

Ok may be you try to install qualcomm augmented ndk in your system and you modify the path from my computer so change the setting:

`my computer-> properties->advanced->environment variables`  user variable form `your computer name`  select `temp path` than select `edit` and remove extra adding path after ";" and dont tuch rest of part `"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"`  click ok  out form your my computer go to eclipse and start your emulator it will working.

Comment: after an eclipse restart is needed

Answer (score 0):

i have just restarted the my fedora OS,
its work for me